# Node.js create simple module with return error

Tags: node.js

index.js

```
var number;

module.exports.setNumer =  function(num)
{
    number = num;
};

module.exports.getInfo = function()
{
    return {

        number : number
    };
};
```

app.js

```
var flight = require('./index');

flight.setNumber(1234);
console.log(flight.getInfo());
```

I got this error

> TypeError: flight.setNumber is not a function

As I'm new for Node.js so please anybody help!

Thank you.

Comment: Your function is named `setNumer` instead of `setNumber`.

Comment: Vsevolod Goloviznin, Thank youuuuuuuuu.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo:

```
module.exports.setNumer =  function(num)
{
    number = num;
};
```

Notice you wrote "setNumer".  And your call is to `setNumber()`.  You're missing a "b" in your definition.

Comment: @webmastx Glad to help. That's a quite frequent issue, but your best bet here is to debug and set breakpoints (or break on exceptions).  You'd be able to do a little debugging analysis and quickly find those issues.